# SharePoint search is not working

Tags: sharepoint-server, search, crawling

I have enabled the SharePoint search to search the content in SharePoint site, library or list. It was working fine up to few months.

But now it is not working. The continuous and full crawl is running fine. But when I am searching the items in the list or library, then it is not get work.

Searchable checkbox is already checked there.

Is there any idea what issues occurred there?

Comment: You could check if items are crawled. Go to Central Administration >Manage service applications > Search Service Application > Under Diagnostics  click Crawl Log and URL View. Paste link to some list and check if items are crawled. If items are crawled then is problem in managed properties (Searchable, retrievable...)

Comment: what did you mean that it doesn't work? No results returned or show an error? What keyword did you use? Like Marko said, you first need to make sure the items are crawled.

Comment: @Kally_MSFT I am trying to search with Item name. Items are crawled. I have picked the items from the log. After search it showing No results returned.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the steps below :-

Open SharePoint Central Admin.

Navigate to Search Service Application.

Open “Search Schema” from the left navigation.

Search managed property “ListItemID”.

Make sure that the “Searchable” checkbox is selected.

Click "OK" to save changes.

Run the full crawl.

Comment: All above steps are already enabled and followed but issues looks same. Is there other way that we can fix this issues?

Answer (score 0):

To fix this SharePoint sudden search issue - you may look into this url:

[How to fix the “Unexpected response from server. The status code of response is ‘500’ in SharePoint 2016 Search](https://global-sharepoint.com/2019/08/20/how-to-fix-the-unexpected-response-from-server-the-status-code-of-response-is-500-in-sharepoint-2016-search/).

Comment: Maybe high memory utilization is problem. If this is cause your people picker won't work either.

Comment: @MarkoTica People picker work fine on this. When I am searching the contents, it showing your search returned no results.

Comment: As Marko mentioned this could be the over memory utilization - we also faced this issue, for our case it was over memory utilization, follow the below link to fix the memory utilization search issue: https://global-sharepoint.com/2019/08/20/how-to-fix-the-unexpected-response-from-server-the-status-code-of-response-is-500-in-sharepoint-2016-search/

Comment: @HabiburRahaman memory utilization is approx 80%. When I am search the content on entire site it returning me "There was an exception in the Database. Please retry your operation and if the problem presists, contact an administrator".